# Check custom listview items on Activity start

Tags: c#, android, list, listview, xamarin

I have a custom Listview in my `C# Android`, each row contains one `textview` and one `checkbox`. I am saving the value (or the text) of the selected row's `textview` in a public list named `usercoin`. Each time the user opens the app, the list usercoin will contain the text of the his `textview` selected items, and I am doing that using `SQLite`. The problem is I want to re-check the items which the `user` have previously selected automatically when the activity starts which are stored in the `usercoin list` as I have previously noted. But I am not able to achieve this.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
 ListView mListView;
MyAdapter adapter;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview);
    List<TableList> list = new List<TableList>();

    list.Add(new TableList("Germany",false));
    list.Add(new TableList("France", false));
    list.Add(new TableList("Finland", false));
    list.Add(new TableList("Germany", false));
    list.Add(new TableList("France", false));
    list.Add(new TableList("Germany", false));
    list.Add(new TableList("France", false));
    list.Add(new TableList("Finland", false));

    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
    mListView.Adapter = adapter;
    mListView.ItemClick += MListView_ItemClick;
}

private void MListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var t = list[e.Position];
    string selected = t.name;
    var ll = e.View as LinearLayout;
    var cb = ll.GetChildAt(2) as CheckBox;
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        cb.Checked = false;
        adapter.changeState((int)cb.Tag, false);
    }
    else
    {
        cb.Checked = true;
        adapter.changeState((int)cb.Tag, true);
    }
}



class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    Context mContext;
    List<TableList> mitems;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<TableList> list)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mitems = list;

    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems.Count;
        }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return mitems[position];
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        DataViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.CoinList, null, false);
            holder = new DataViewHolder();
            holder.tv = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CoinName);
            holder.iv = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
            holder.cb = convertView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
            convertView.Tag = holder;
        }
        else
        {
            holder = convertView.Tag as DataViewHolder;

        }
        holder.cb.Tag = position;

        holder.tv.Text = mitems[position].Name;
        holder.cb.Focusable = false;
        holder.cb.Checked = mitems[position].bl;
        holder.iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.dapao);
        holder.cb.CheckedChange += Cb_CheckedChange;
        return convertView;

    }

    private void Cb_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = sender as CheckBox;
        if (e.IsChecked && !mitems[(int)cb.Tag].bl)
        {
            mitems[(int)cb.Tag].bl = true;
            this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if (!e.IsChecked && mitems[(int)cb.Tag].bl)
        {
            mitems[(int)cb.Tag].bl = false;
            this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    internal void changeState(int tag, bool v)
    {
        mitems[tag].bl = v;
        this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public class DataViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public ImageView iv { get; set; }
    public TextView tv { get; set; }
    public CheckBox cb { get; set; }

}
public class TableList : Java.Lang.Object
{
    private string v;



    public TableList(string name, bool b)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.bl = b;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool bl { get; set; }
}
}
}
```

For example, when the user first run the app and select `France` and `Germany` from the `listview`, next time he re-opens the app, the `usercoin` list will contain France and Germany. Now the question is how can I check the `checkboxes` corresponding to those values in the `listview`. I have tried to do so by including this code in `MyAdapter : BaseAdapter class`:

```
if (Class1.usercoin.Contains(item.CoinAbr))
        {
            Class1.adapter[(int)holder.cb.Tag].bl = true;
            this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

But when this code get executed, the previously checked items are checked plus some other items which the user haven't checked previously are also checked. So how can I check the previously checked items in the `Listview` on the app start ? Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Check, does your `bl` variable in `list` will change after your checkbox will be selected/deselected. I'm not best in c#, but I think you are changing data in adapter, but doesn't change this in your list.

Comment: @grabarz121 No it does not